# Proper way to make array from integer division in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, integer

tl;dr I want to make an array from the division by 5 results:

```
20 => [5,5,5,5]
16 => [5,5,5,1]
7  => [5,2]
```

My current implementation is straightforward yet too large. How can I make it simpler and shorter?

```
  max_count = 5
  total_count = input_value

  count_array = []
  div = total_count / max_count
  mod = total_count % max_count
  div.times { count_array << max_count }
  count_array << mod unless mod == 0
```

Comment: `16 => [5,5,5,1]`

Comment: `20.divmod(5) #=> [4, 0]`. Contains the all the information you require i.e. the quotient and the remainder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't need `total_count`.
2. `div.times { count_array << max_count }` is `[max_count] * count_array`
3. Using splat, we can simplify it further

```
max_count = 5

[*[max_count] * (input_value / max_count), input_value % max_count] - [0]
```

Alternatively, using [divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod)

```
max_count = 5

n, mod = input_value.divmod(max_count)
[*[max_count] * n, mod] - [0]
```

Last line can also be written as:

```
(Array.new(n) { max_count } << mod) - [0]
```

or as Stefan suggested in the comment, using [Numeric#nonzero?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F):

```
Array.new(n, max_count).push(*mod.nonzero?)
```

Comment: ...or `([max_count] * n).tap {  |arr| arr << mod if mod > 0 }`. `rem` may be a better name than `mod`.

Comment: I'd use `Array.new(n, max_count).push(*mod.nonzero?)` – [`nonzero?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F) returns the receiver if it's not zero or `nil` otherwise.

Comment: @Stefan that's really nice, I did not know about `nonzero?`, today I learned :) I'll edit and add it.

Answer (score 0):

One option more:

```
d = 5
n = 24
Array.new(n/d){d}.tap{ |a| a << n%d if (n%d).nonzero? }
#=> [5, 5, 5, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

```
max=5
num=48
q, r=num.divmod(max) # => [9, 3]
Array.new.fill(max, 0, q).push(r.nonzero?).compact
# => [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3]
```

Comment: This might result in an array ending with `0` (which the OP doesn't want)

Comment: Just realized that :P.Thanks @Stefan.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
[20].tap{|a| a.push(5, a.pop - 5) while a.last > 5} # => [5, 5, 5, 5]
[16].tap{|a| a.push(5, a.pop - 5) while a.last > 5} # => [5, 5, 5, 1]
[7] .tap{|a| a.push(5, a.pop - 5) while a.last > 5} # => [5, 2]
```